# Remove "Reorder" Link from customer side

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-account, link, reorder

How to **remove "Reorder" link** from customer's Account "My order tab" and also from Order view page of Customer.

I want to do this from customer's account. Admin can reorder from back end.

Magento version : 1.7

Comment: Always ask question with specific Magento version.

Comment: Please check my updated que.

Answer (score 3):

Go to 
 `System->Configuration->Sales -> Reorder`

Set the option “Allow Reorder” to No.

Comment: Hi.. I want to remove link from front side only.

Comment: this solution disable reorder completely

Answer (score 1):

You can remove reorder link from history.phtml file by comment that code.
app\design\frontend\Your_theme\default\template\sales\order\history.phtml

Around line no 69.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove from below files.

My order tab : `template/sales/order/history.phtml`

Order view page : `template/sales/order/info/buttons.phtml`

Comment: Ok but I am not able to overrite any block file for this.We also need to hide Reorder link from My Account -> Account Dashboard -> Recent Orders

Comment: As per my answer, you can remove from directly phtml. no need to overwrite any block.